# What is the difference between a Region Chest and Cache?

Tags: destiny-2

In some places you will find cache chests, which contain some items and at least in the EDZ are Fallen looking round barrel chests.

However I've also found gold standard looking chests, which when opened show a message of Region Cache opened.

How do these loot boxes differ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest difference is that Region Chests don't respawn. Once you've opened the gold chest, you can't open it again. Ever. On any other character. They contain 3 faction regional faction tokens, 1000 glimmer, and occasionally a Rare or Legendary Engram.

The standard caches respawn frequently, and generally contain a (1) regional faction token, some glimmer, roughly 250, I believe, and the chance of a Rare or Legendary Engram.

Comment: If I'm planning on a second character is it prudent to save a few for that character?

Comment: Not necessarily. Gear comes pretty easily, and the chance of getting gear from the regional chests is pretty small. Glimmer is shared across characters, and any character can turn in tokens, so it's really up to you.